# Calculating black squares on black/white board.

Tags: word-problem

The table below shows a square board in which strips of white squares alternate with strips of black and white squares. A larger board is to be made in the same way. If it has $36$ black squares, how many white squares will there be on this larger board?

[image]

I've found that the answer is supposedly $133$ but I would love to understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Notice the pattern, if this is specifically a square, if there are $n^2$ black squares there are $(2n+1)^2$ total squares used black and white.  Removing the black squares from this gives the total number of white squares as $(2n+1)^2-n^2=3n^2+4n+1$ white squares.  For $n=6$ this gives $3\cdot 6^2+4\cdot 6 + 1 = 108+24+1=133$

Comment: Thank you for adding the formulas. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple

For a $7 \times 7$ $(3\cdot2+1)$ board..there are $9$ $(3\cdot3)$ black squares

Similarly for a $13\times13$ $(6\cdot2+1)$ board..there will be $36$ $(6\cdot6)$ black squares

So white squares=$169-36=133$

Why $13$ ?
Because $6\times6$ black squares means $6$ rows containing black squares and $7$ rows containing white squares ..

Similar case for columns...

So $13$ columns and $13$ rows

Comment: Thank you for the concise, clear response.